# What's the difference between DSUB25F and DSUB25M?

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate printer port in multisim.

But I found that printer port(25 pin) also have two choices,such as DSUB25F and DSUB25M.

What's the difference between them? I couldn't find anything in google.

Thank you~

Comment: Female and Male.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M = male = has pins.
 F = female = has sockets

**Photo: DB 25F / Female / sockets**

DB25M at top.
 DB25F at bottom.

[image]

Comment: I was sure someone was already writing an answer when I wrote my comment and would have a nice picture.

Comment: Is that only the different connector? Or do their function also have differences?

Comment: @sam - Given the information that has been provided to you, can you please indicate what efforts you have made to research this question yourself? Knowing what people know and knowing how hard they are trying can be a useful guide when people ask questions that look trivially easy to do some basic research on themselves. In some cases people may not be able to do this and answering such questions is then entirely acceptable.

Comment: @sam - As a guide - the DB25 male and female connectors are used for many things. Some standards demand that one or other be used in a given role. eg in RS232 they have different roles. There are so many standards and uses that a general answer is not only long and hard to give - and has already been answered at length many times over on the internet. This connector is much less used now than it once was. Once common for RS232 use, it was  superseded for this purpose by the DB9 M&F connectors and RS232 is now much less used in a domestic environment due to USB taking over many of its roles.

Comment: Thank you all for advised,and now I know the trend you said. I am new to this area, and I have tried to search google withe 'connector female male difference' keyword. What I got is 'A female connector is commonly referred to as a jack and has a center conductor with a hole in it to accept the male pin.' but it is only said about the structure difference,I couldn't find any other functional difference.Do they only have the structure difference? And how to google for better answer in this area?